# ansible ERROR! conflicting action statements in playbook

Tags: ansible

Im trying to run a playbook and get syntax errors as follows, need to understand where my error is: ERROR! conflicting action statements

The error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/chk_ddboost.yml': line 4, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

```
tasks:
- name: ddboost plugin check
  ^ here

---
- hosts: netbackup
  tasks:
- name: ddboost plugin check
  stat:
    path: /usr/openv/lib/ost-plugins/libstspiDataDomain.so
  register: stat_result
  fail: msg="DDBoost not installed on system"
  when: stat_result.stat.exists = False

- name: run command as root
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  command: "/usr/openv/netbackup/bin/admincmd/bpstsinfo -pi -stype DataDomain"

- name: show output
  debug: msg="{{result.stdout_lines}}"
```

Comment: Please fix indentation for tasks in your code snippet, because this way you should have got another error message.

Comment: thank u that was correct.

Answer (score 1):

Missing dash:

```
- name: ddboost plugin check
  stat:
    path: /usr/openv/lib/ost-plugins/libstspiDataDomain.so
  register: stat_result

- fail: msg="DDBoost not installed on system"
  when: not stat_result.stat.exists = False
```